# Need help adding 240V outlet to my residential garage

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, 240v

I am adding a 240V outlet to my garage, wired from directly outside the garage (12" from panel to outlet).

I have a conveyor dryer unit for a small business I run from home. This unit has a 4 pronged plug with 2 hots, a ground, and a neutral.

I don't see a neutral bar in my electrical panel. I assume I don't have one. How should I proceed?

[image]

[image: panel]

Comment: You'd have to look locally for your paid help.

Comment: FYI you have multiple, mutually-incompatible breaker types in your panel. That’s a code violation and risks damaging the bus, possibly causing a fire (the shapes are close enough to seem to fit but are not actually identical). Given that the main is an Eaton, the BR breakers are probably correct and the MPs probably need to go, but double-check the panel label to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of the Siemens breakers. Replace with an Eaton BR1515 or BD1515, and an Eaton BR250.  Use a torque screwdriver to tighten ALL your screws to the stated torque spec, that is the #1 way to avoid meltdowns from bad connections.  Unfortunately this was not common knowledge until recently.

Comment: @CameronN - other people editing your question to improve it is a Stack Exchange feature. Please read https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Answer (score 4):

The bar with the white wires connected is the neutral bar. It's also the acting as the ground bar, and has bare wires connected, which applies in the main service panel and ONLY in the main service panel. Since this is a meter-main, we can be certain it IS a main panel.

Normally (check your specific panel labeling for specifics of your panel) ground wires can share 2 or 3 wires (depending on size/gauge) to a hole. Neutral wires must each have their own un-shared hole in the bar. The torque value may be different for 1, 2, or 3 ground wires and for different sizes of wires. All connections (to the bar, and to the breaker) must be torqued to specifications, neither too tight nor too loose - a torque screwdriver is going to be available in the electrical aisle most places you'd buy breakers and receptacles.

If you are installing a 240V outlet in a garage, you will need a 240V GFCI breaker to supply it (at least under current codes. If your LAHJ is using some ancient code revision that may not apply to you, but you should consider that the changes come to code via accumulated deaths and consider biting the extra expense anyway.)

Note that the exposed connections at the top of your main breaker are live/hot at all times and for all intents and purposes unfused. Don't get careless near them.

Comment: Thx E.  My concerns is... hooking up the 4 prong with a neutral that is also a ground....  How will this config provide pwr to one of my components without providing power to the other that needs a knob rotation to power on?

The guy I bought the conveyor heater from said they initially hooked it up incorrectly and when the power button was switched on for the conveyor... the heat element automatically turned on (it should not).  He said they then had to swap the hots? to fix the problem.

I'd just like to know I'm doing something that will get the proper result when complete.

Comment: Neutral is always grounded, at the main panel. Neutral is a current-carrying conductor, normally, and carries the return current for any 120V loads (perhaps the motor?) Ground should only carry current in the event of a fault, hopefully leading to a nice quick breaker trip. If the heater is a normally wired 240V heater there was something odd going on with the internal wiring for it to come on with the motor, if it has a control switch in line with it. Switch the phase of the hots at the receptacle would make no difference to that.

Comment: He may have understood the fix or explained it improperly.  Thx.  Follow-up question.  If I purchase the torque driver... how will I know at what torque to apply each connection?

Comment: By reading the panel label for the Neutral bar, and by reading the instructions with the breaker, though that information is usually also molded right into the breaker itself, as well.

Comment: The GFCI you speak of... this is simply a GFCI unit that is an upgrade from the standard 240v 30amp breaker, and takes it's place, right?  It's not a separate unit... or are you talking about a GFCI plug outlet?

Comment: Yes, for 240V the only (practical) GFCIs are breaker GFCIs. Apparently there are some industrial 240V receptacle-type ones, but you could buy several GFCI breakers for the price of one...